# Is it a good idea to use "lazy val" for correctness?

Tags: scala, lazy-initialization

In Scala, declaring a `val` as `lazy` means that its value won't be evaluated until it's used for the first time. This is often explained/demonstrated as being useful for optimization, in case a value might be expensive to compute but not needed at all.

It's also possible to use `lazy` in a way that it's necessary for the code to work correctly, rather than just for efficiency. For example, consider a `lazy val` like this:

```
lazy val foo = someObject.getList().find(pred) // don't use this until after someObject filled its list!
```

If `foo` weren't lazy, then it would always contain `None`, since its value would be evaluated immediately, before the list contained anything. Since it is lazy, it contains the right thing as long as it isn't evaluated before the list is filled.

My question: is it considered okay to use `lazy` in places like this where its absence would make the code incorrect, or should it be reserved for optimization only?

([Here](https://github.com/MightyPirates/OpenComputers/blob/7e836e73f1cdc2f0f2035cbc9ed5202676b672c5/src/main/scala/li/cil/oc/common/asm/ClassTransformer.scala#L54-L59) is the real-world code snippet that inspired this question.)

Comment: It's not exactly without precedent.  Many languages include short-circuit boolean operators that are often used as a fence to test one condition before evaluating another that depends on it.  For example: `if (someObject != null && someObject.someValue == 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is considered okay in general. A relatively common use is to initialize fields of a supertype when they have to depend on the state of a subtype (but even there you need to be careful). See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html.

In this particular example, "don't use this until after someObject filled its list" seems to put extra burden on clients of this class, so I'd look for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Laziness is required for correctness in certain circumstances, like an infinite recursive data structure for example, but you haven't guaranteed correctness at all here. It's still possible to call `foo` before the list is populated. There are other better ways to write this that actually guarantee correctness. Those ways should be preferred if at all possible.

The first way is to make `someObject` immutable, so that its list must be fully populated before this object gets a reference to it. This is hard to do when you're accustomed to imperative code, but it's not as much of a burden as you might think. The payoff is you **know** the list is valid when you call `foo`. You don't have to guess whether `foo` is okay to call yet or not.

The next best way is to make `someObject.getList()` return a `Future`, or something similar like a monix `Task` or cats-effect `IO`. This is typically used when `getList()` is expensive to compute or might possibly fail, like if it requires a network call. A `Future` is how you specify in the type system that a value is still being computed, but it's not valid to use until the computation is finished.